# in pageview:- sometime itemBuilder called 2-3 times when swipe

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

here is my code:-

```
PageView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                          key: PageStorageKey('player_home'),
                          itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                            return VideoPlayerSurfaceNew(
                              key: PageStorageKey('page-$position'),
                              currentWave: state.userFeedDbList[position],
                              videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController,
                              videoPlayerControllerCallBack:
                                  videoPlayerControllerCallBack,
                            );
                          },
                          itemCount: state.userFeedDbList.length,
                          controller: _myPageViewController,
                          onPageChanged: (page) {

                          },
                        ),
```

and here is my controller

```
_myPageListener() {
if (_myPageViewController.offset >=
        _myPageViewController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
    !_myPageViewController.position.outOfRange) {
  _userFeedBloc.dispatch(LoadUserFeedNextPage());
  _userFeedDbBloc.dispatch(LoadUserFeedDb());
}
}
```

in this itembuilder called many times when i swipe UP or DOWN.

Comment: Could you provide your controller and some compilable version of your case?
It could help

Comment: @dubace 

`_myPageViewController = new PageController()..addListener(_myPageListener);

_myPageListener() {
    if (_myPageViewController.offset >=
            _myPageViewController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
        !_myPageViewController.position.outOfRange) {
      _userFeedBloc.dispatch(LoadUserFeedNextPage());
      _userFeedDbBloc.dispatch(LoadUserFeedDb());
    }
}`

Comment: It's difficult to detect where the problem is because of many side effects in your listener: a few dispatches of bloc that can cause rebuilding your widget.

Comment: @dubace yeah, but it helps in pagination. if i remove that logic then how can i do pagination?

Comment: @dubace please tell e another way to pagination using BLOC.

Comment: Can you please provide some minimum compilable code that has same problem?

Comment: @dubace
please open link
https://justpaste.it/4vabg
there is two file code